# The smallest non-zero singular value of AB

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, spectral-theory, svd, singular-values

For a matrix $A$, let $σ_{min}(A)$ denote the smallest $\textbf{non-zero}$ singular value of A.

I saw some materials (e.g. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e74f/89ac85239811b295787619e73c99fc867724.pdf)
says that
$$σ_{i}(AB)≥σ_{i}(A)σ_{n}(B),~~~ i=1,\cdots,n$$

Here $A$ and $B$ are rectangle matrix with dimension, say, $p\times n$ and $n\times m$. This holds for even zero singular value. So if $B$ is not full rank, then $\sigma_n(B)$ is $0$ and the above bound is trivial.

My question is if the following inequality holds:
$$σ_{min}(AB)≥σ_{min}(A)σ_{min}(B)$$

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general it isn't true. E.g. when $A$ is a nonzero row vector and $B$ is a nonzero column vector such that $AB=0$, both $\sigma_\min(A)$ and $\sigma_\min(B)$ are positive but $AB$ has not any nonzero singular value.

The inequality holds, however, when $A$ has full column rank and $B\ne0$ or when $A\ne0$ and $B$ has full row rank. Since the latter case reduces to the former when we consider $(AB)^T$, we shall only deal with the first case. In this case, $Bx=0$ or $ABx=0$ if and only if $x\in\operatorname{range}(B^\ast)^\perp$, and whenever $ABx\ne0$, we have
$$
\|ABx\|
=\left\|A\frac{Bx}{\|Bx\|}\right\|\|Bx\|
=\|Ay\|\|Bx\|
$$
for some unit vector $y$. Therefore, by Courant-Fischer minimax principle,

$$
\sigma_\min(AB)
=\min_{\|x\|=1,\,x\in\operatorname{range}(B^\ast)}\|ABx\|
\ge \min_{\|y\|=1} \left\|Ay\right\| \min_{\|x\|=1,\,x\in\operatorname{range}(B^\ast)}\|Bx\|
= \sigma_\min(A)\sigma_\min(B).
$$

Comment: Maybe I confused my point. I'm not saying $B$ is full rank, I just mean if $B$ is not full rank the bound in material is trivial. And in my definition, all $\sigma_{min}$ are the smallest non-zero singular value, this means we do not care if they are full rank or not.

Comment: @Heydude There was actually an error in my old answer. In general, we have $\sigma_\min(M)=\min_{\|u\|=1}\|Mu\|$ only when $M$ is a tall matrix. So, we must take the shapes of $A$ and $B$ into account. Please see my new edit.

Comment: Thanks for the fix!:)

Answer (score 4):

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$. Let $\sigma_*(A)$ be the smallest non-zero singular value of $A$ if $A \neq 0$, and zero if $A = 0$. I use $\sigma_*$ to avoid confusion with the smallest singular value.

#### Counter-example for a general lower bound

Let $A = \lceil 1, 0 \rfloor$ (a diagonal matrix). Then $\sigma_*(A) = 1$.

- Let $B = \lceil 1, 2 \rfloor$. Then $AB = \lceil 1, 0 \rfloor$, and $1 = \sigma_*(A) \sigma_*(B) = \sigma_*(AB) = 1$.
- Let $B = \lceil 2, 1 \rfloor$. Then $AB = \lceil 2, 0 \rfloor$, and $1 = \sigma_*(A) \sigma_*(B) < \sigma_*(AB) = 2$.
- Let $B = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$. Then $AB = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and $\sqrt{2} = \sigma_*(A) \sigma_*(B) > \sigma_*(AB) = 1$.

Hence a general lower (or upper) bound which works for every matrix does not exist. Additional assumptions are needed.

#### Relaxed sufficient conditions

The accepted answer by user1551 gives sufficient conditions for the stated lower bound to hold: $A$ is column-independent and $B \neq 0$, or $B$ is row-independent and $A \neq 0$.

I'll note that the lower bound holds with the following relaxed condition:

$$\mathrm{range}(BB^T) \subset \mathrm{range}(A^T) \lor \mathrm{range}(A^T A) \subset \mathrm{range}(B).$$

Note that:

- when $A$ is column-independent, $\mathrm{range}(A^T) = \mathbb{R}^n$,
- when $B$ is row-independent, $\mathrm{range}(B) = \mathbb{R}^n$,
- $\mathrm{range}(A^T) = \mathrm{null}(A)^{\perp}$,
- $\mathrm{range}((AB)^T) = \mathrm{range}(B^T A^T) \subset \mathrm{range}(B^T)$,
- $\mathrm{null}(B) \cap \mathrm{range}(B^T) = \mathrm{null}(B) \cap \mathrm{null}(B)^{\perp} = \{0\}$.

Suppose $A = 0$ or $B = 0$. Then $\sigma_*(AB) = \sigma_*(0) = 0 = \sigma_*(A) \sigma_*(B)$, and the lower bound holds.

Suppose $A \neq 0$, $B \neq 0$, and $\mathrm{range}(BB^T) \subset \mathrm{range}(A^T)$. Then

$$
\begin{aligned}
{} & \sigma_*(AB) \\
= & \min \left\{||AB x|| : x \in \mathrm{range}((AB)^T) \land ||x|| = 1 \right\} \\
\geq & \min \left\{||AB x|| : x \in \mathrm{range}(B^T) \land ||x|| = 1 \right\} \\
= & \min \left\{\left\lVert A \frac{Bx}{||Bx||}\right\rVert ||Bx|| : x \in \mathrm{range}(B^T) \land ||x|| = 1 \right\} \\
\geq & \min \left\{\left\lVert A \frac{Bx}{||Bx||}\right\rVert : x \in \mathrm{range}(B^T) \land ||x|| = 1 \right\} \\
\cdot \; & \min \left\{||Bx|| : x \in \mathrm{range}(B^T) \land ||x|| = 1 \right\} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

For the first factor,

$$
\begin{aligned}
{} & \min \left\{||A \frac{Bx}{||Bx||}|| : x \in \mathrm{range}(B^T) \land ||x|| = 1 \right\} \\
= & \min \left\{||A \frac{Bx}{||Bx||}|| : x \in \mathrm{range}(B^T) \setminus \{0\} \right\} \\
= & \min \left\{||A y|| : y \in \mathrm{range}(BB^T) \land ||y|| = 1 \right\} \\
\geq & \min \left\{||A y|| : y \in \mathrm{range}(A^T) \land ||y|| = 1 \right\} \\
= & \sigma_*(A).
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore

$$\sigma_*(AB) \geq \sigma_*(A) \sigma_*(B).$$

Suppose $A \neq 0$, $B \neq 0$, and $\mathrm{range}(A^T A) \subset \mathrm{range}(B)$. By the previous case

$$\sigma_*(AB) = \sigma_*((AB)^T) = \sigma_*(B^T A^T) \geq \sigma_*(B^T) \sigma_*(A^T) = \sigma_*(A) \sigma_*(B).$$

#### Application

I'll now describe an interesting application for the bound. Consider $||(AB)^+||$, where $||\cdot||$ denotes the operator 2-norm, and $+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose inverse. It is not difficult to show (e.g. by employing singular value decomposition) that $||A^+|| = \sigma_*(A)^+$. Supposing now the relaxed sufficient conditions, we get the nice upper bound

$$||(AB)^+|| \leq ||A^+|| ||B^+||.$$

Note that this result is not trivial, since in general $(AB)^+$ does not equal $B^+ A^+$.

#### Open question

Is the relaxed condition also necessary?